# Switching between fragments and fragments with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

am having three fragments say A,B and C, one with viewpager that it contains multiple fragments(say fragment B has) in it.

while switching to fragment b will render the fragment viewpager contents after moving to other fragment and back to fragment b, here it will reload the content again.

i just want to stop destroying fragments once it get rendered??

Thanks in Advance.

sample code of adapter:

```
public class QuestionsSortPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public QuestionsSortPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            QuestionsSortByVotes byVotes = new QuestionsSortByVotes();
            return byVotes;
        case 1:
            QuestionsSortByActivity byActivity = new QuestionsSortByActivity();
            return byActivity;
        case 2:
            QuestionsSortByHot byHot = new QuestionsSortByHot();
            return byHot;
        case 3:
            QuestionsSortByDate byDate = new QuestionsSortByDate();
            return byDate;
        case 4:
            QuestionsSortByMonth byMonth = new QuestionsSortByMonth();
            return byMonth;
        default:
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: What ViewPager Adapter do you use?

Comment: am using FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: FragmentPagerAdapter will keep all fragments, it just destroy the view of fragment which is invisible to user.

Comment: But in my case, while moving to other fragment which is outside this viewpager(using nav drawer) and coming to this fragment which contains above 5 fragments. its getting reloaded again. Here fragments will request to fetch data from server, i dont want to make another request to the server again and again.

Answer (score 0):

FragmentPagerAdapter will keep all fragments, it just destroy the view of fragment which is invisible to user, for example, if you scroll page from 1 to 2, then the view of page 0 will be destroyed, but the instance of page 0 will still be retained by adapter.

You can change this default behaviour by calling the method `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)`, if you set `limit` to 2, then the view of page 0 will also be retained.

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state.

Comment: this is not the case here.